# Reverse numbers in a cell divided by a decimal point

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a corrupted price table like this:

```
          price
1         06.4
2         80.80
3         40.22
4         42.50
5         21.54
6         25.22
7         07.30
8         287.85
9         6.40
10        221.85
11        10.6
12        22.72
13        23.4
14        4.22
```

The prices got mixed up like you can see in line 1 where ...

```
1         06.4
         ...
7         07.30
```

... should be ...

```
1         4.06
         ...
7         30.07
```

... and so on.

The number behind the decimal point needs to be at first if it's only one number.

For example:
A price looks like 9.90 or 19.00 but not like 09.90 or 00.19. So if it is 09.90 it should actually be 90.09.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: what should be the third value? 22.40?

Comment: Third value is correct. just line 1, 11 and 13 are the wrongway und need to reversed

Comment: @AlexOBrady You keep changing the "rules"; this makes it very difficult to help. Please spend some time (1) carefully writing down the rules for changing entries, and (2) providing **minimal representative sample data**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not overwrite the column `a` so that you may compare and see that the
rows 1 11 13 15 16 17  which needed to be reversed were indeed reversed. The criteria being any number that starts with a zero need to be reversed and also any number that ends with a one digit in the cents should also be reversed:

```
transform(df,b=sub("(\\b0.*)\\.(.*)|(.*)\\.(\\d\\b)","\\2\\4.\\1\\3",a))
        a      b
1    06.4   4.06
2   80.80  80.80
3   40.22  40.22
4   42.50  42.50
5   21.54  21.54
6   25.22  25.22
7   47.30  47.30
8  287.85 287.85
9    6.40   6.40
10 221.85 221.85
11   10.6   6.10
12  22.72  22.72
13   23.4   4.23
14   4.22   4.22
15  00.99  99.00
16   01.9   9.01
17   10.3   3.10
```

DATA:

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(3L, 17L, 13L, 14L, 6L, 10L, 15L, 
11L, 16L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("00.99", 
"01.9", "06.4", "10.3", "10.6", "21.54", "22.72", "221.85", "23.4", 
"25.22", "287.85", "4.22", "40.22", "42.50", "47.30", "6.40", 
"80.80"), class = "factor")), .Names = "a", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This works good but I still have values like 04.30 that need to change to 30.04 because 04 in the price column would be just 4. If it starts with 0 it must be switched too. sorry I forgot about that scenario in the first place

Comment: What is the logic you are using? Which row is that? How do you know when to change? You must tell the computer that otherwise it will not know when to change and when not to change

Comment: Can you please add atleast one value to your example that would cater for your whole data in that when a solution is given it solves the problem

Comment: a price looks like 9.90 or 19.00 but not like 09.90 or 00.19. So if it is 09.90 it should actually be 90.09. I know this is wierd but Excel ruined the price colomn and this is restorng work

Comment: edit your initial question adding all those examples there

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "          price
1         06.4
2         80.80
3         40.22
4         42.50
5         21.54
6         25.22
7         47.30
8         287.85
9         6.40
10        221.85
11        10.6
12        22.72
13        23.4
14        4.22", colClasses = "character", header = T)

df$corrected_price <- sapply(strsplit(df$price, "\\."), function(x) {
    if (nchar(x[2]) == 1) x <- rev(x);
    paste(x, collapse = ".");
})
df;
#    price corrected_price
#1    06.4            4.06
#2   80.80           80.80
#3   40.22           40.22
#4   42.50           42.50
#5   21.54           21.54
#6   25.22           25.22
#7   47.30           47.30
#8  287.85          287.85
#9    6.40            6.40
#10 221.85          221.85
#11   10.6            6.10
#12  22.72           22.72
#13   23.4            4.23
#14   4.22            4.22
```

---

Or another method without `sapply`:

```
mat <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(df$price, "\\.")), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE);
mat[nchar(mat[, 2]) == 1, ] <- mat[nchar(mat[, 2]) == 1, ][, 2:1];
df$corrected_price <- apply(mat, 1, paste, collapse = ".");
```